# Python: Map list of two-entry-dicts to dict with first entry as key and second as value

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
[{'date': 1, 'value':5}, {'date':2,'value':3}, ...]
```

and want to map the values this two keys to this:

```
{1:5, 2:3, ...}
```

How can I do this in a nice way?

Comment: And what determines the key and the value? I am *guessing* that you want the key to be the `date` value from input dict and the value the `value` value.

Comment: The keys of the dicts in the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> lis = [{'date': 1, 'value':5}, {'date':2,'value':3}]
>>> {x['date']:x['value'] for x in lis}
{1: 5, 2: 3}
```

Comment: This only works in Python 2.7+. For previous version refer to Simeon Visser's answer.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2:

```
>>> lis = [{'date': 1, 'value':5}, {'date':2,'value':3}]
>>> result = dict((x['date'], x['value']) for x in lis)
{1: 5, 2: 3}
```

For Python 3:

See Ashwini's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:
The following Python code will extract the dictionary values:

```
dict(map(lambda L: L.values(), lst))
```

Comment: I just deleted a similar answer (`dict(v.values for v in lis)`) which I think is wrong: it's relying on the order of the items, which is not guaranteed by the `dict` type

Comment: @icecrime I had the same thought, but you were faster ;)